# uploading profile pic in hapijs 17.0

Tags: ajax, file-upload, multipartform-data, hapi.js, content-length

I am using hapijs version 17.0.1. I am trying to upload an image using ajax request on a hapijs route. Here is my AJAX code to upload profile pic:

```
var image_file_input = document.getElementById("user_profile_upload");

image_file_input.onchange = function () {
    if(this.files != undefined)
    {
        if(this.files[0] != undefined)
        {
            var formData = tests.formdata ? new FormData() : null;
            if (tests.formdata)
            {
                //alert(file)
                formData.append('image_file', this.files[0]);
                formData.append('userId', user_id);
                formData.append('memberId', member_id);
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "/v1/User/uploadUserPic",
                data: formData,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: "multipart/form-data",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    var errMsg = null;
                    var resData = null;
                    if(data.statusCode == 200)
                    {
                        resData = data.result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(data.message)
                    }
                },
                error: function(error){
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Hapijs route Code:

```
    var uploadUserPic = {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/v1/Module/uploadUserPic',
        config: {
            description: 'Update Image For User',
            tags: ['api', 'User'],
            auth: 'session',
            payload: {
                output: 'stream',
                parse: true,
                allow: 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            validate: {
                payload: {
                    userId : Joi.string().regex(/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i).required(),
                    memberId: Joi.string().required(),
                    image_file: Joi.object().required(),
                },
                failAction: FailCallBack
            }
        },
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            var resultData = null;
            var error = null;
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                var multiparty = require('multiparty');
                var fs = require('fs');
                var form = new multiparty.Form();
                form.parse(request.payload, function (err, fields, files) {
                    if(err)
                    {
                        error = err;
                        resolve();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
                        var img_dir = "./files/users/";
                        mkdirp(img_dir, function (err) {
                            if (err)
                            {
                                error = err;
                                console.error(err);
                                resolve();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var oldpath = files.image_file.path;
                                var newpath = "./files/users/"+requestPayload.userId+".png";
                                fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
                                    if(err)
                                    {
                                        error = err;
                                    }
                                    resolve();
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }).then(function (err, result) {
                if(err) return sendError(err);
                if(error) return sendError(error)
                return {
                    "statusCode": 200,
                    "success": true
                };
            });
        }
    }
```

The above code gives me following error `cannot read property 'content-length' of undefined` on line `form.parse(request.payload, function (err, fields, files) {});`

Please let me know If I am doing something wrong. If I replace the url in ajax request with anohter url that I have written in php then it works perfectly. which means that something is wrong with my hapijs/nodejs code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good post on how to handle file uploads in Hapi.js (written in version 16) https://scotch.io/bar-talk/handling-file-uploads-with-hapi-js

Since you are using `payload.parse = true`, I am not seeing a particular reason why you have to use `multiparty`. I have the following working code that would save files (of any type) uploaded from client into uploads directory on the server (Please do not use directly on production as no sanitation is done)

```
        {
            path: '/upload',
            method: 'POST',
            config: {
                payload: {
                    output: 'stream',
                    parse: true,
                    allow: 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                validate: {
                    payload: {
                        files: Joi.array().single()
                    }
                }
            },
            handler: function(request) {
                const p = request.payload, files = p.files
                if(files) {
                    console.log(`${files.length} files`)
                    files.forEach(async file => {
                        const filename= file.hapi.filename
                        console.log(`Saving ${filename} to ./uploads`)
                        const out = fs.createWriteStream(`./uploads/${filename}`)
                        await file.pipe(out)
                    })
                }
                return {result: 'ok'}
            }
        }
```

You can use the following curl command to test

```
curl http://localhost:8080/upload -F 'files=@/path/to/a/note.txt' -F 'files=@/path/to/test.png' -vvv
```

There are a few issues with your code. First in your `$.ajax` call, you have specified `contentType` twice, although it's not a syntax error but it's careless to code like that. Second the function's signature inside your .then() block is incorrect. You are mixing the idea of Promise and callback. I don't think the following line will be triggered

```
        if(err) return sendError(err);
```

One last trivial thing, you said you are using Hapi 17 but based on the handler function's signature

```
handler: function (request, reply) {
...
```

Seems you are not totally onboard with Hapi17 as the new signature is

```
handler: function (request, h) {
```

And it's not just the rename of `reply` to `h`.

Comment: `sendError` is just formatting my error. secondly I know its `h` instead of `reply`. but I upgraded from hapi 14 to 17 so I had to change it in whole project. Also `h` sounds bit awkward to me. So I considered `reply` just as a variable denotation and called the properties/function of `h` with `reply` variable. By the way Thanks for the help mate. I will check your solution and get back to you.

Comment: It worked like a charm mate. Thanks for your help. Glad to accept your answer.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad to help :D